# ResultSet object has no attribute '%s' when parsing array in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup to parse some HTML.  Here's the code:

```
//Build container for 'dates' divs
uniqueDatesBucket = []
for i in soupBucket:
   uniqueDate = i.find_all('div', {'class': 'event-b58f7990'})
   uniqueDatesBucket.append(uniqueDate)    

print uniqueDatesBucket
```

uniqueDatesBucket, when printed, works as expected and produces the following (an abbreviated version below):

```
[[<div class="event-b58f7990"><div class="event-ad736269">JAN</div><div class="event-d7a00339">06</div></div>, <div class="event-b58f7990"><div class="event-ad736269">JAN</div><div class="event-d7a00339">06</div></div>]]
```

I want to parse Month/Day from the above array.

```
uniqueMonth = []
uniqueDay = []

for i in uniqueDatesBucket:
    uniqueMonthDay = i.find_all('div')
```

However, this fails and I get the following error:

```
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  I clearly see that the array has divs that contain Month/Day so not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think probably it's because the uniqueDatesBucket is list of list. 
try this.

```
for i in uniqueDatesBucket[0]:
    uniqueMonthDay = i.find_all('div')
```

Comment: you rule !  Thanks so much.  Works now.